# How to create two pie charts using a split condition?

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have this sample dataset:

```
   sex  Country
1   M   Austria
2   F   Germany
3   F   Portugal
4   M   Portugal
5   F   France
6   M   Germany
```

I want to create a piechart but separating and adding the data according to sex. That is, what I expect as a result is equivalent to if I wanted to separate them in a geom_bar in ggplot by the same variable. In the same visualization, but separated

From R base I do not know if there is any way to do it within the same method or I would have to separate the data previously in two tables and represent them separately

I know that using piechart is not the optimal way to represent data, but I need to do it that way for a specific request

**Example of the same process but as a geom_bar**

[Same dataframe, but separate viz for the sex variable (colors means different countries)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSF2X.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with base R:

```
old <- par(mfrow=c(1,2))

pie(table(df$Country[df$sex == "M"]))
pie(table(df$Country[df$sex == "F"]))

par(old) # reset par
```

[image]

---

with ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(table(df)),
       aes(x = "", y = Freq, fill = Country)) +
 geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill") +
 facet_grid(cols = vars(sex)) +
 coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
 theme_void()
```

[image]

---

where `df` is:

```
df <- read.table(text = "   sex  Country
1   M   Austria
2   F   Germany
3   F   Portugal
4   M   Portugal
5   F   France
6   M   Germany", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Great. Just one question. What would I have to do if there were more women than men in my data? When I try to replicate it, the men's graph comes out with an unfilled portion precisely because there are more women's annotations; when I remove the polar coordinate trick and leave it as bars it is more visible: the stacked bar of women is larger than that of men. In the example, you get the same unfilled portion by changing one "M" with a "F" in the data. In any case, thank you very much

Comment: you need to add: `position = 'fill'` in `geom_bar`. I edited my answer. Let me know if it good for you now

Comment: It does. Thank you so much